# SemaphoreSlim and async/await

Tags: c#, synchronization, semaphore

This works:

```
int _counter;
readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);

async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (_semaphore.Wait(0))
    {
        Title = $"{ ++_counter}";
        await Task.Delay(1000); // simulate work
        Title = $"{ --_counter}";
        _semaphore.Release();
    }
}
```

After first click further buttons clicks are ignored until work is finished. `Tittle` can be `1` or `0`.

And this doesn't work

```
void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (_semaphore.Wait(0))
    {
        Test(); // moving code into separate method
        _semaphore.Release();
    }
}

async void Test()
{
    Title = $"{ ++_counter}";
    await Task.Delay(1000); // simulate work
    Title = $"{ --_counter}";
}
```

Clicking button continuously will rise `Tittle` to `2`, `3`, and so on.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`async void` only makes sense in event handlers. It is a special type of asynchronism. It means "fire and forget".

You don't want to fire and forget the `Test()` method. You want to wait for it to return.

Change your `Test` signature to:

```
// Note that it returns a "Task". A task is an awaitable promise.
async Task Test()
{
   //...
}
```

And then await it on your event handler:

```
async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     if (_semaphore.Wait(0))
     {
        await Test(); // moving code into separate method
        _semaphore.Release();
    }
}
```