# async method in foreach

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous, multitasking

I'm writing Windows Forms Application and i have a problem with blocking UI while loading data from FTP server.

I have a list of servers from which i'm getting info. So, when i click button 'Get from all' i get info from each of them.

```
private void GetInfoToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in infoDataGridView.Rows)
        this.GetInfoAsync(row);
}
```

I run new task when getting info from server to prevent UI blocking. The method **GetInfo** is async:

```
private async void GetInfoAsync(DataGridViewRow row)
{
    Server server = (Server)row.Cells[0].Value;
    row.Cells[1].Value = Resources.GettingIcon;

    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        server.Data = dataGetter.GetData(server);
    });

    row.Cells[1].Value = Resources.FinishedIcon;
}
```

The main question is: why foreach starts new iteration before **GetInfoAsync** finished? I'm using **await** keyword in this method, so execution should not finish before data getting finished.

Comment: You don't `await` `GetInfoAsync`.

Comment: You are not using await in the click event handler, they are all fire-and-forget.

Comment: @tkausl Why *should* it be awaited?

Comment: @Crowcoder What work needs to be done after they finish, that isn't being done as a result?

Comment: @Servy because OP wants to wait for the function to complete before starting the next iteration.

Comment: @Servy "The main question is: why foreach starts new iteration before GetInfoAsync finished?"

Comment: @tkausl What makes you think that?  Why shouldn't each row be processed before the previous has been?

Comment: @Servy `The main question is: why foreach starts new iteration before GetInfoAsync finished?`

Comment: `GetInfoAsync` is a fire-and-forget method, `async void`, it does not return a task. It will, however, return immediately upon the first encounter of `await T` where `T` is a task that isn't complete by the time you try to await it, which is the `Task.Run` part in your code. As such your loop will call `GetInfoAsync` which will execute up until you start another task, and then return back to your loop. If you want to complete this async method before continuing the loop, change it to `async Task` and await it in the loop as well.

Comment: It seems everybody has to run into `async void` issue once.. [I did too](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40239795/1997232).

Comment: Came upon this SO looking for `IAsyncEnumarable<T>` pattern of `await foreach` on events I have recently seen since C# 8.0.  I realize this is years later but not see any need for the present -4 Votes on this question.  Hope this person wasn't discouraged from continuing learning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *reason* why your loop will move on to the next item and call `GetInfoAsync` again, before the previous one has completed is because `GetInfoAsync` is a fire-and-forget method.

It is fire-and-forget because it has been declared as `async void` and internally starts a new task.

The fact that `GetInfoAsync` *awaits*  this sub-task does not magically make the `GetInfoAsync` method **wait** until this sub-task has completed before it returns.

Instead, here's what happens:

1. Your loop will call `GetInfoAsync` for the first row.
2. `GetInfoAsync` will execute right up until it has spawned the sub-task using `Task.Run`.
3. It will then, using the magic of `await T` queue up a continuation task after this sub-task
4. It will then return back to the loop

Once the sub-task for the first row has completed, the continuation task will be scheduled for execution.

It you want your loop to call `GetInfoAsync` and *wait* before it moves on to the next item you need to change the method with the loop:

1. It needs to be `async` as well
2. It needs to `await` the `GetInfoAsync` method
3. And thus `GetInfoAsync` must return a `Task` as well.

Here's your final code:

```
private async void GetInfoToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in infoDataGridView.Rows)
        await this.GetInfoAsync(row);
}

private async Task GetInfoAsync(DataGridViewRow row)
{
    Server server = (Server)row.Cells[0].Value;
    row.Cells[1].Value = Resources.GettingIcon;

    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        server.Data = dataGetter.GetData(server);
    });

    row.Cells[1].Value = Resources.FinishedIcon;
}
```